# How to get specific action by tapping on push notification message?

Tags: codenameone

The cn1 developer guide says

> ...but if you click "OK" in the dialog, your push() callback will be
> run. Clicking OK is analogous to the user tapping on the notification.

This is in case if *Ok button* action was not set up and it just opens the app in a state that it was left.

But what if I want to have different, specific actions by tapping on the button and on the notification message itself? Regular buttons have `.getActionId()`, but what about the push notification itself?

Comment: For that case you usually use push type 3 and include a hidden payload in the push message that triggers special behavior within your app.